# Number of Threads in Monotouch application

Tags: c#, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin, async-await

I'm using `Task` and `TaskCompletionSource` code in my application in scenarios that are frequently invoked, such as downloading a images from the Internet asynchronously from a 'scrolling table view'. This allows me to write async/await code without touching the UI thread for downloading/caching operations.

e.g.:

```
public override Task<object> GetCachedImage (string key)
    {
        UIImage inMemoryImage = sdImageCache.ImageFromMemoryCache (key);

        //
        // Return synchronously since the image was found in the memory cache.
        if (inMemoryImage != null) {
            return Task.FromResult ((object)inMemoryImage);
        }

        TaskCompletionSource<object> tsc = new TaskCompletionSource<object> ();

        //
        // Query the disk cache asynchronously, invoking the result asynchronously.
        sdImageCache.QueryDiskCache (key, (image, cacheType) => {
            tsc.TrySetResult (image);
        });

        return tsc.Task;
    }
```

The `GetCachedImage` is invoked multiple times because a table view may have lots of images to be downloaded and the user may scroll the table view as well.
The Task itself does not take too long to be performed (in some cases the result is returned synchronously), so I'd expect that the system create a lot of threads but also REUSE them. However I'm seeing in the console the following output:

`Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #149`

The number of threads always get bigger and I'm worried my application is creating too many threads and may get stuck because of that after a long period of usage. What does the `Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #149` mean? Are threads being created and destroyed? Are threads being reused? Does my application have `#149` live threads? Can (should) I limit the max number of threads?

---

**EDIT**

As suggested by @usr I ran my application again and stopped the debugger to see how many threads were there, see the screenshots:
[image: Debugger threads]
[image: Debugger console]

Looks like 38 threads were created, but some of them were destroyed, I am right?
Does that mean that the `Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #...` message will always appear with a bigger number as long as the application is running? Why aren't threads re-used ?

Comment: Why would the system even create any threads? I don't see anything that would create a thread in your code.

Comment: I'm not a `ThreadPool` expert, but I can see in the documentation that `Task` uses `ThreadPool` threads to perform work in background. The problem is 'why too many threads are being created'?

Comment: If you use `Task.Run()` or something like that, sure. But not if you use `Task.FromResult()` or `TaskCompletionSource`, because then there is no work to perform.

Comment: What does that thread-pool debug output even mean? I'm not sure. It does not necessarily mean that this many threads are running. Pause the debugger and look how many threads are there.

Comment: I edited my question with screenshots of the debugger output as @usr suggested.

Comment: While I can't comment from the standpoint of a thread pool expert, I can say that you probably shouldn't worry about it.  Use the TPL library as much as you want, .NET will handle the gritty thread management for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thread number shown in the Application Output is the nth thread created, not the nth running thread.

For example:

```
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #123
```

means that in the entire app's lifetime 123 threads have started. It does not say anything about how many threads are currently running.

The opposite message:

```
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #123
```

means that this thread has now exited.

And if you now create a new thread, you'll see this:

```
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #124
```

This means that to know how many threads are currently running, you can count the number of "Thread started" lines and subtract the number of "Thread finished" lines.

An alternative solution is to to just look at the Threads pad (like your screenshot), and count the number of threads there instead.